# jquery drag/drop - get the id of the element being dragged from on drop

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

Is there a way to get the id (or some other attribute value) from the element being dragged from, when an element is being dropped?

For instance, on the left, I have a stack of divs that I can drop images into.  On the right I have a div that holds the images.  When I drag an image from the right to a div on the left, I can get info on what was dragged [image name] and what it was dropped on [div id].

If I now want to drag an image from a div on the left to the div on the right, how can I get the id of the div that the image was on when I drop the image on the div on the right.

Sorry if this is confusing.

Comment: I imagine so; can you provide a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) showing an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) demo to reproduce what you're working with? Help us to help you by making it easier to see what you're doing... =)

Answer (score 6):

Below is a runnable solution for you.

You have a container with draggable elements (these could be images) on the left and you have containers on the right in which you can drop these draggable elements. On drop of an element from left to right you will see an alert showing with the id of the element being dropped as well as the container from which the item was dropped.

If you want to know what element an item was dragged from, you can get it by accessing the parent of the dragged element on drop since dragging an element only changes its position relative to its container.

```js
$(function() {
      $( ".draggable" ).draggable();
 
        $( ".droppable, #droppable-inner" ).droppable({
            activeClass: "ui-state-hover",
            hoverClass: "ui-state-active",
            drop: function( event, ui ) {
                alert(ui.draggable.attr('id') + ' was dropped from ' + ui.draggable.parent().attr('id'));
                $( this ).addClass( "ui-state-highlight" );
                
                // Move the dragged element into its new container
                ui.draggable.attr('style','position:relative');
                $(this).append(ui.draggable);
                
                return false;
            }            
        });
  });
```

```css
.draggable { 
  width: 100px;
  padding: 0.5em;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.droppable {
  width: 230px;
  min-height: 120px;
  padding: 0.5em;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="container1" class="droppable">

    <div id="d1" class="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
        <p>Drag me to my target</p>
    </div>

    <div id="d2" class="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
        <p>Drag me to my target</p>
    </div>

    <div id="d3" class="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
        <p>Drag me to my target</p>
    </div>
 
</div>

<div id="container2" class="droppable ui-widget-header">
    <p>Drop here!</p>
</div>
 
<div id="container3" class="droppable ui-widget-header">
    <p>Drop here!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I appreciate the work, but it is not quite what I am needing.  Using your example, when d1 is dropped onto one of the containers on the right, the alert should tell me the id of the container that is on the left (where d1 came from).

Comment: I have updated the code to what you were looking for here: http://jsfiddle.net/dv3EL/2/

Also, I have edited my answer.

Comment: Nevermind. I have another solution which makes more sense. Since dragging an item from one container to the other only changes the position of the dragged item, its parent container remains the same until you move it into its new container so on drop you can grab the container the element came from by looking at its parent ui.draggable.parent(). See updated code here: http://jsfiddle.net/dv3EL/4/